# Compare two pipe delimited files using Unix

Tags: unix, scripting, sh

`File_1.txt`:

```
emp_id|emp_name|emp_dob
111|Alex|08/29/1994
222|John|05/12/1997
333|Sam|08/24/1987
```

`File_2.txt`:

```
emp_id|emp_dob|emp_name
111|08/29/1994|Alex
444|05/12/2000|John
222|05/12/1997|Brad
```

Need to compare `File_1.txt` and `File_2.txt` using columns which are mention in header(`head -1 File_1.txt`), `emp_id` can be used for join condition

After comparison,  below files should be generated

`Mismatch.txt`  ## Contains mismatch values as per `emp_id`

```
File_name|column_name|emp_id|File_1_value|File_2_value
File 1|emp_name|222|John|Brad
```

`Missing_Rows.txt`  ## Contains `emp_id`s which are missing in File 1 or File 2

```
File_name|emp_id
File 1|444
File 2|333
```

I'm able to join the 2 files using join command but unable to find the Missing and Mismatch rows details.

```
join -j1 -t'|' -o1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2,2.3 <(cat  File_1.txt|awk -F'|' '{print $0}'|sort  -t '|' -k1,1)<( cat  File_2.txt|awk -F'|' '{print $0}'|sort -t '|' -k1,1) > joinfile.txt`
```

Comment: `Mismatch.txt ## Contains mismatch values as per emp_id` could you please do provide more details on how this file is getting generated? I could see `222` value is present in both of the files, kindly elaborate more on same on it.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, That's what I'm unable to code. So I have posted a question

Comment: I understand that and I am also trying to help here. My question is related to algorithm of it, I mean what is the Logic of getting required output, in your shown output I have posted that previous comment question, if you could answer it I could to help here.

Comment: 222 Value is present in mismatch.txt file as it is having different emp_name, I want to compare cols on the basis of emp_id

Comment: Could you please do let me know if my solution has worked for you? It worked for me with shown samples.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, thanks for your help!!.I'm new to Stackoverflow so not aware of the process. Code is working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. It will create 2 output files named `Mismatch.txt` and `Missing_Rows.txt` as per requirement.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="|"
  print "File_name|column_name|emp_id|File_1_value|File_2_value" > "Mismatch.txt"
  print "File_name|emp_id" > "Missing_Rows.txt"
}
FNR==NR{
  empId1[$1]=FILENAME OFS $0
  empId2[$1]=$2
  empVal[$1,$2]=$0
  next
}
{ empId3[$1] }
!($1 in empId1){
  print (FILENAME,$1) > "Missing_Rows.txt"
  next
}
($1 in empId1) && !(($1,$3) in empVal){
  print (FILENAME,empId2[$1],$NF) > "Mismatch.txt"
}
END{
  for(i in empId1){
    if(!(i in empId3)){
      split(empId1[i],arr,"|")
      print (arr[1],arr[2]) > "Missing_Rows.txt"
    }
  }
}
' file1.txt file2.txt
```